# Altium designer routing blocked by old board shape

Tags: pcb-design, altium, routing

I am trying to re-route my board, so I changed the board size using the "board planning mode".
Now, I'm routing, and some tracks are "blocked" by something looking very much like the old board limit.
Is there  a workaround or I failed somewhere??

[image: PCB Routing blocked]

Another question linked to that, at the end of the "auto routing", it tells me there is 1 or 2 connection failed to complete, but I see none. How to find them?

Comment: Typically, keep-out areas are in pink. Are you sure you don't have keep outs where you want to route ? What does the 3D view show (key 3) ? To find unrouted tracks you can do a Design Rules Check in Tools, and look for Net antennaes.

Comment: show all layers, see if there is something you missed.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are routing on the wrong layer, you should be running traces on red or blue (usually top or bottom) copper layers. Purple is usually a mechanical layer.

Comment: The HUD says top layer

Comment: Purple is the colour I gave to these specific connections, it's shown at bottom left, I'm on the top layer

Comment: Then why is the top layer tab highlighted in the picture?